# How can I tell a custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to use properties in resource files if custom properties not available

Tags: java, spring

I am using a custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to pull certain properties from the database.

I would like to extend the functionality so that for properties not found in the database it will look in properties files defined as context:property-placeholder in the Spring XML.

I tried setting the mode to fallback and override, and I tried calling super.resolvePlaceholder(..) but everything returns blanks.

Is there a Spring way to do this short of reading the property files manually?